# Extending 60 days tourist visa-in-advance in Maumere, Flores, Indonesia

Tags: visas, indonesia, visa-extensions

I am in Indonesia on a 60 days tourist visa-in-advance and want to extend it by 30 days in Maumere, Flores. In order to do this [I will need a sponsor](http://www.lashworldtour.com/2013/09/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-tourist-or-social-visa.html).

There are several questions and answers on this topic online, but many of them are several years old [[2008](http://www.trip-pub.com/forum-70658295/VISA-EXTENSION-IN-FLORES-MAUMERE.html), [2012](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/indonesia/maumere-visa-extension-bliss), [2014](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/indonesia/visa-extension-in-maumere-flores-indonesia), [2015 (but contains little relevant information)](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/indonesia/visa-extension-to-60-days?page=4)]. I would need some up-to-date information to decide whether I should do the extension in Maumere or fly to Bali to do it.

I would ask people who have done the extension in Maumere recently kindly to share their experiences. More specifically:

**The main question(s)**:

1. Which hotel or agency did you get your sponsor from?
2. How much did they charge?
3. Would you recommend them?

I would appreciate if you could also answer the following questions (for example, by incorporating the information in your answer):

4. How long did the process take?
5. Did you visit the embassy before contacting your sponsor or did your sponsor give you the relevant papers?
6. What were the opening hours of the immigration office?
7. Did they follow the Christian calendar, the [Indonesian calendar](http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/indonesia/) or their own calendar (i.e. there was no way knowing when they are on holidays)?

I apologize asking several questions within one question, but to me these questions are related and too small to make a question for each of them. They work more as a guideline to direct your answer to a correct direction than a requirement for a good answer. If you do not know answer for some of those questions, please just ignore them. Since this particular immigration office does not have an internet site, I could not find the opening hour information anywhere. I hope the answers to this question will also help other travelers out there.

Comment: Why not just do a visa run?

Comment: Voting to close this question as it's asking for recommendations of a specific visa agent, of which there are dozens.

Comment: While answers based on personal experience are fine, this is basically asking for a list of personal experiences - which doesn't really match the Q&A format. Voting to close until it's suitable.